# redux-toolkit asynchronous action returns undefined

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

In the code below, when logging the action, I receive the payload value as undefined:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const getMenuItems = createAsyncThunk(
  "menuItems/getMenuItems",
  async () => {
    axios
      .get("https://run.mocky.io/v3/eaf5dd77-5306-4093-ba7b-66364be1eacc")
      .then((response) => response)
      .then((item) => item.data);
  }
);

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "menuItems",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getMenuItems.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log("state:", state);
      console.log("action:", action.payload); // action.payload == undefined
    });
  },
});

export default slice.reducer;
```

I expected the return value from `getMenuItems` to be equal to `action.payload`.

Comment: Your thunk doesn't need to be declared as an `async` function, you can simply return the promise you're creating there anyway. Right now you've got an async function that doesn't return anything, which turns into a Promise that resolves with `undefined`. Also the `.then((response) => response)` doesn't do anything, I'd remove that.

Comment: You still have the inner function declared as `async`. Try `() => axios.get(...)` there, just return the entire promise chain.

Comment: I understand, thank you
I have to use return before axios, while I used it inside axios and there is no need to write then first, as a result, the following code is obtained:

Comment: export const getMenuItems = createAsyncThunk(
  "menuItems/getMenuItems",
  async () => {
    return axios
      .get("https://run.mocky.io/v3/eaf5dd77-5306-4093-ba7b-66364be1eacc")
      .then((response) => response.data)
  }
);

Answer (score 0):

> I expected the return value from `getMenuItems` to be equal to
> `action.payload`.

The `getMenuItems` action doesn't return anything other than the implicit Promise object because the function is declared `async`, it immediately resolves to `undefined` because nothing is waited on.

You can simply return the Promise chain directly:

```js
export const getMenuItems = createAsyncThunk(
  "menuItems/getMenuItems",
  (_, thunkApi) => {
    return axios
      .get("https://run.mocky.io/v3/......")
      .then(item => item.data)
      .catch(error => {
        return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
      });
  }
);
```

Or you can use `async/await` and `try/catch`:

```js
export const getMenuItems = createAsyncThunk(
  "menuItems/getMenuItems",
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data } = axios.get("https://run.mocky.io/v3/......");
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: I understand, thank you I have to use return before axios.get()